# Developing very strong Quadriceps

Tags: strength, muscle, strength-training

I'm 43 old and I have practiced martial arts for the last few years. My thighs have strong muscles but I don't think they are strong enough. Some of the practitioners in my martial art have thighs that are strong as iron 'literally'.

Strong thighs are important since we absorb hits using them.

**What is the best way to strength the thighs at home with minimal equipment and minimal time (I have dumbbells and Iron Gym Upper Body Workout)?** Are there some drills relevant to Body by Science method (Big 5)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squats. Lots and lots of squats. Squat variations. Lots and lots of squat variations and progressions. Lunges and lunge variations as well.

Have a look at something like Convict Conditioning and work your way up to pistol squats. When you can perform 5 consecutive ass to grass pistol squats, chances are you'll have some pretty strong thighs.

Answer (score 3):

Your first step would be making sure your body has the fuel to develop and recover with your exercise. To develop muscle effectively you should be at least eating at a maintenance, preferably at a bulk.

Next, carry on doing martial arts! I did Tae Kwon Do for about 6 years in my youth and as a result I have a very well developed lower body. MY legs can take a battering too due to the conditioning that I did. If you have time and money, pick up another martial art that focus on legs: TKD, Muay Thai, Kickboxing, etc.

You can do a lot at home too once you have mastered squats (credit: [r/bodyweightfitness](https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/playground/squat))

#### Advanced Progressions:

Note: In terms of mobility, the more weight you bring backwards, the more your knee has to go over your toe, so shrimp squats and deep step ups require more ankle mobility than pistols

- Pistol Squat
- Deep Step-Up
- Shrimp Squat